# Reload R package with compiled extensions

Tags: r, package

Is it possible to reload an R package with native extensions in an R session?
I am developing [Rliblinear](https://github.com/lynaghk/Rliblinear/), which uses several `C` functions.
If I make a change to R code in the package, I can just reinstall and reload;

```
$ R CMD build Rliblinear
$ R CMD INSTALL Rliblinear
```

and then in an `R` shell;

```
> detach("package:Rliblinear", unload=TRUE)
> library(Rliblinear)
```

However, the `C` functions are not affected unless I restart the `R` interpreter.
Is there a way I can force the interpreter to reload the shared object, `Rliblinear.so`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will list your loaded dynamic link libraries:

```
library.dynam()
```

and this will unload `Rliblinear.*` in the Rliblinear package.

```
library(Rliblinear)

# ... run package ...

detach("package:Rliblinear", unload = TRUE)
library.dynam.unload("Rliblinear", system.file(package = "Rliblinear"))
```

You can issue `library.dynam()` again just to check that its no longer listed.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to do my tests on the command-line with [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) to be sure I get a fresh R session.  You can do this with `Rscript` too.

So my work flow would be

```
$ R CMD INSTALL Rliblinear/    ## alternatively, install from tarball
$ r -lRliblinear -e'someExpressionFromThePackage()'
```

which you can also wrap into a single line with `&&` and/or precede with a clean step.

Comment: Do you need to install too, or is littler doing some magic to use the package tarball?

Comment: Sorry, meant to write R CMD INSTALL, will fix.

Answer (score 4):

here is an extension to Mr G. Grothendieck answer, if embedded in "yourpackage" one can recompile it with one shot from R console:

```
reload <- function( path ){

   detach("package:yourpackage", unload = TRUE)
   library.dynam.unload("yourpackage", system.file(package = "yourpackage"))

   path <- paste( "--vanilla  CMD INSTALL ", path )

   system2( 'R', path  )
   require("yourpackage")
}
```

then from R:

> yourpackage::reload( '/home/me/yourpackage' )